# Concurrent set_secret calls to Azure KeyVault API in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

I have a python script which currently writes secret strings to Azure KeyVault.
This works well if the list is small, but I have have 4000+ KVs to write and this is taking 50mins each time the pipe runs.

I'm using the library like this:

```
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient, KeyVaultAuthentication, KeyVaultId
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def auth_callback(server, resource, scope):
...

client = KeyVaultClient(KeyVaultAuthentication(auth_callback))
data = sys.stdin.read()
if data:
    print('Writing outputs to keyvault '+kvURL)
    outputs = json.loads(data)
    n = 0
    for op in outputs.items():
        key = baseEnv + '-' + baseFunction + '-' + op[0]
        key = key.replace('_', '-')
        val = str(op[1]['value'])
        print('Storing: ' + key + ' = ' + val)
        try:
            secret_bundle = client.set_secret(kvURL, key, val)
        except:
            print('err in key'+key)
            exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE)
            n += 1
    print(str(n)+' secrets written.')
else:
    print('OK nothing to do.')
```

As the script just needs to make concurrent calls to the API, I don't explicitly need multiprocessing or thread concurrency, just an async way of instantiating the client object.

The [docs](http://%20https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-sdk-python/blob/master/docs-ref-services/key-vault.md#examples) don't help me much, and I don't know any c# so I'm failing to translate any async methods I see.  Any idea of how I should approach this welcome.  Especially around instantiating multiple client objects.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, almost of all Azure SDK APIs are wrapped the related REST APIs. So after I reviewed Azure KeyVault REST APIs, there is not an API supports to set secrets in bulk in only one request.

Therefore, the only solution to reduce the time cost of running your script is make it parallelization via [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) or third-party packages in Python.

Here is two ways as my recommended.

1. Follow the first code sample of `multiprocessing` to run it parallelly via a process `Pool`, such as below

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Pool

   def setSecret(op):
       key = baseEnv + '-' + baseFunction + '-' + op[0]
       key = key.replace('_', '-')
       val = str(op[1]['value'])
       print('Storing: ' + key + ' = ' + val)
       ret = (key, 1)
       try:
           secret_bundle = client.set_secret(kvURL, key, val)
       except:
           print('err in key'+key)
           ret = (key, 0)
       return ret

   if __name__=='__main__':
       proc_num = 100
       with Pool(proc_num) as p:
           rets = p.map(setSecret, outputs.items())
       n_successed = sum([ok for _, ok in rets])
   ```
2. You can refer to the blog [Easy parallel HTTP requests with Python and asyncio](http://skipperkongen.dk/2016/09/09/easy-parallel-http-requests-with-python-and-asyncio/) to rewrite your code to directly call the REST API [Set Secret - Set Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/setsecret/setsecret) and run concurrently.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PeterPan. I considered these approaches but in the end as I wrapped the call to the python script in bash, I just split the list of outputs I had to send to KV and passed them to backgrounded, iterative calls to the python script and did a wait for them to finish.

Comment: @volvox Sure. In bash, you also can accelerate your script running via [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/GNU-Parallel.html) command. Hope it helps, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are now new packages for working with Key Vault in Python that replace `azure-keyvault`, which each support asynchronous operations that make concurrent calls more straightforward:

- [azure-keyvault-certificates](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-certificates/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-certificates/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-keys](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/migration_guide.md)

[azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) is also the package that should be used with these for authentication.

There's documentation for asynchronously creating secrets in the [secrets package README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/README.md); here's an example of how you could use the async client for your use case (with some bits simplified for readability), making use of [asyncio's `gather` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

```
import asyncio
from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets.aio import SecretClient

kvURL = "https://{vault-name}.vault.azure.net"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(kvURL, credential)

async def set_secrets():
    async with client:
        data = sys.stdin.read()
        if data:
            print("Writing outputs to keyvault " + kvURL)
            outputs = json.loads(data)
            n = 0
            coroutines = []
            for op in outputs.items():
                key = "secret" + str(n)
                val = "value"
                print('Storing: ' + key + ' = ' + val)
                try:
                    coroutines.append(client.set_secret(key, val))
                except:
                    print("err in key " + key)
                    exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE)
            return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
        else:
            print("OK nothing to do.")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(set_secrets())
loop.close()
print(results)  # prints a list of secrets created
```

(I work on the Azure SDK in Python)